# NFT trait type of array

Tags: cryptocurrency, nft, opensea

Let's say I have an NFT project where the trait `Specimens` is dynamic for it's number of occurrences so its an array/list. It could be structured like the following:

```
{
  "name": "5016",
  "id": "5016",

  "attributes": {
    "Biome": "CACTI",
    "Composition": "6K",
    "Specimens": [
      {
        "order": "Araneae",
        "type": "Spider",
        "name": "Agelenidae",
        "size": 1,
        "left": 375,
        "top": 423
      },
      {
        "order": "Blattodea",
        "type": "Roach",
        "name": "Anapidae",
        "size": 2,
        "left": 28,
        "top": 438
      },
      
    ]
  }
}
```

Or even

```
{
  "name": "5016",
  "id": "5016",
  "attributes": {
    "Biome": "CACTI",
    "Composition": "6K",
    "Specimens": [
        "Agelenidae",
        "Anapidae"
    ]
  }
}
```

Although this is valid metadata I am worried it wont work on most marketplaces, with the ability to filter like other NFT projects. There could be between 1 - 30 different specimens in any order so having them as named traits in Attributes wouldn't work either. Is there any other alternative for structuring this data we could do to have it work nicely with filter UI's on marketplaces to determine trait rarities?